# Error: multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0&sockPath=/sockjs-node ./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css

Tags: angular

I am not able to resolve this Error.

I've tried listing the inner version used by angular-cli using the code below :

*npm ls @ngtools/webpack*

And I also manually installed *@ngTools/webpack* with the same version of angular-cli using :

*npm install @ngtools/webpack@11.0.5 --save-dev*

But the error still persists. What am I doing wrong?

Code below:

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { HomeComponent } from './PAGES/home/home.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './COMPONENTS/footer/footer.component';
import { CheckoutComponent } from './PAGES/checkout/checkout.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './PAGES/login/login.component';
import {HeaderComponent} from './COMPONENTS/header/header.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './COMPONENTS/banner/banner.component'; 
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProductsComponent } from './COMPONENTS/products/products.component';
import { CheckoutProductsComponent } from './COMPONENTS/checkout-products/checkout-products.component';
import { CheckoutSubtotalComponent } from './COMPONENTS/checkout-subtotal/checkout-subtotal.component';
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import { firebaseConfig } from './CONFIG/firebase.config';
     




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    CheckoutComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    CheckoutProductsComponent,
    CheckoutSubtotalComponent
  ],
  imports: [   
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatIconModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,    
    MatFormFieldModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  ],
  providers: [],            
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the angular.json file below

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ecommerce-project": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ecommerce-project",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/boostrap.min.css"
              

            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ecommerce-project:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ecommerce-project:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ecommerce-project:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ecommerce-project:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ecommerce-project:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ecommerce-project",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "1a9dce89-6789-45fa-85e6-98e39024c7d2"
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Had you tried to delete your `node_modules` folder and install the packages again?

Comment: Yes I’ve tried deleting both node_modules and package-lock.json file and reinstall using npm install but it didn’t work.
Is there anything I’m doing wrong?